# Error when attempting to use Google AppEngine datastore admin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the AppEngine console I have enabled datastore administration. I also enabled the remote API. However, when I try to access it I see the following message:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL
```

Many people seem to have a 400 (Not found) or 500 (Error), but none of the fixes for these issues seem to fix this permission problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions issue was caused by having login for my webapp restricted to one domain, while I was accessing the AppEngine administration from another domain.

As an example, AppEngine administration was being performed from `support@my_developer_domain.com`, whereas all the logins for the app itself were in the form `xyz@client_company_domain.com`.

The solution was to get the client to assign me an email address at their own domain (`andy@client_company_domain.com`) then invite that account to be a developer for the web app. After accepting the invitation and logging in with this account, the datastore admin page was visible.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Your suggestion fixed my issue too.